# Что означает это условие?

Tags: c

Есть такое условие не могу понять, что оно означает. Надеюсь, данного фрагмента кода будет достаточно:

```
unsigned long input_bytes = 0, output_bytes = 0;
short *first_references, *next_references;
unsigned char *terminators;
unsigned long shifter = 0;

total_codes = 1 << maxbits;
first_references = malloc (total_codes * sizeof (first_references [0]));
next_references = malloc ((total_codes - 256) * sizeof (next_references [0]));
terminators = malloc ((total_codes - 256) * sizeof (terminators [0]));

if (!first_references || !next_references || !terminators)
    return 1;                       // failed malloc()

memset (next_references, 0, (total_codes - 256) * sizeof (next_references [0]));
memset (terminators, 0, (total_codes - 256) * sizeof (terminators [0]));

(*dst)(maxbits - 9);    // first byte in output stream indicates the maximum symbol bits

// This is the main loop where we read input bytes and compress them. We always keep track of the
// "prefix", which represents a pending byte (if < 256) or string entry (if >= FIRST_STRING) that
// has not been sent to the decoder yet. The output symbols are kept in the "shifter" and "bits"
// variables and are sent to the output every time 8 bits are available (done in the macro).

while ((c = (*src)()) != EOF) {
    int cti;                            // coding table index

    input_bytes++;

    if (prefix == NULL_CODE) {          // this only happens the very first byte when we don't yet have a prefix
        prefix = c;
        continue;
    }

    if ((cti = first_references [prefix])) {    // if any longer strings are built on the current prefix...
        while (1)
          while (1)
            if (terminators [cti - 256] == c) { // we found a matching string, so we just update the prefix
                prefix = cti;                   // to that string and continue without sending anything
                break;
            }
            else if (!next_references [cti - 256]) {    // this string did not match the new character and
                next_references [cti - 256] = next;     // there aren't any more, so we'll add a new string
                cti = 0;                                // and point to it with "next_reference"
                break;
            }
            else
                cti = next_references [cti - 256];      // there are more possible matches to check, so loop back
    }
    else                                        // no longer strings are based on the current prefix, so now
        first_references [prefix] = next;       // the current prefix plus the new byte will be the next string
```

Смущает последнее условие

```
   if ((cti = first_references [prefix])) {
```

Как мы узнали, что есть более длинная строка чем текущий префикс? Что вообще делает это условие? Сравнивать cti (который на первой итерации цикла NULL, что в С тоже самое, что 0) с 0 вроде бы надо с помощью `==`, и почему выражение взято в скобки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скобки там нужны именно для того, что бы компилятор понял, что мы написали одно равно, а не два осознанно. И перестал ругаться.

Это условие можно расписать так

```
cti = first_references [prefix];
if (cti != 0) {
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться дальше.